# There is no implicit reference conversion from generic type to 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject'

Tags: c#, generics

I'm have created a base class with has the starting code:

```
 public abstract class BaseServices<TObject> : IDisposable
   where TObject : EntityObject
{
    public TObject Get(int id)
    {
        return _context.Set<TObject>().Find(id);
    }
}
```

on the other hand my derived class contains:

```
 public class AmountDLL : BaseServices<Tbl_Amount>
//:Base<Tbl_Amount>
{
    public override ICollection<Tbl_Amount> GetAll()
    {
        return base.GetAll();
    }
}
```

when i run the code it gives error that is:
**The type 'Tbl_Amount' cannot be used as type parameter 'TObject' in the generic type or method 'BaseServices'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Tbl_Amount' to 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject'**
Please suggest me what is wrong with my code
Thanks

Comment: Where is the `Tbl_Amount` class?

Comment: Tbl_Amount is database table

Comment: Your Tbl_Amount-Class must have EntityObject as BaseClass.

Comment: Where does it come from?

Comment: @Nikolaus Can you tell me how

Comment: Can you add the Class-definition of it?

Comment: Is `Tbl_Amount` derived from `EntityObject`?

Comment: @Dom yeah it is derived from entiryobject

Comment: is it the same EntityObject?

Comment: @Nikolaus Tbl_Amount is the table name i am using EFW concept here.

Comment: what is EFW concept?

Comment: Entity Framework

Comment: can you provide the code of Tbl_Amount including the usings? Like I did in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tbl_Amount-class has to look like:

```
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;

public class Tbl_Amount : EntityObject
{
  //Class code
}
```